# Time Issue xx hours ago

Tags: date-time

I'm facing a strange issue, first time in my life :)
After publishing a post/page/custom post type, it's tell that published 10 hours ago. It's happening always, for all posts. 
As I've deployed a VPS for hosting my websit

Comment: Tells it where? What are your time zone settings?

Comment: My Time Zone is UTC + 6. I set both of the server timezone and WordPress timezone to UTC + 6.